# Using XAMPP in a network of three PCs

Tags: php, networking, xampp

I have three PCs connected through a network HUB. I have XAMPP installed on one one of them. I want to use a webapp running on XAMPP, from other PCs as well.

Trying to access the PC, using its IP, but it is not working.

I am using a variable for base URL of that site, and written 127.0.0.1/sitename in it. Shouldn't I change this? Or this will it work also from other PCs?

Comment: does put online button help? any firewalls? antivirus...

Comment: so disable or make exceptions for xampp. maybe first try to disable everything and look if it works

Comment: hmm, k. wht abt this 'Also I am using a variable for BASE url of that site, and written 127.0.0.1/sitename in it, should i change this or this wuill work also from other PCS Need quick responses please.'

Comment: don't get your problem yet but if you have xamp installed and put online and nothing is blocking it your page should be online don't know your project or configuration you trying to accomplish..

Comment: All 3Pcs are appearing in windows Xp workgroup, i am able to access files of each other, but when accessing xampp, it shows page, server took too  long to respond..

Comment: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is local mashine not local network mashine instead use IP address

Comment: yeah em using machines IP address to access xampp